# Inconsistency of GLS Estimator in the Presence of Predetermined Regressors and Serial Correlation

Tags: time-series, econometrics, generalized-least-squares, exogeneity

Let be the linear model:
$$y_i = x_i'\beta + \varepsilon_i$$
Using its matrix form, consider strictly exogenous assumption and spherical assumption, respectivelly:
$$E[\varepsilon | X]=0, \quad E[\varepsilon \varepsilon'|X]= \sigma^2 I_n$$
We know that the spherical assumption is equivalent to i) $E[\varepsilon_i^2|X]= \sigma^2$, and ii) $E[\varepsilon_i \varepsilon_j|X]=0$, $i \neq j$.

Under these conditions we have that the OLS estimator is BLUE. However, if the spherical condition is violated, we still have the unbiased OLS estimator, but we no longer have efficiency.  Thus, through an appropriate transformation, we can correct this problem using the BLUE GLS estimator.

According to Hayashi Econometrics book (Section 1.6 Generalized Least Squares (GLS)):

> All sanguine conclusions about the finite-sample properties of GLS rest on
> the assumption that the regressors in the generalized regression model are strictly
> exogenous

It is worth noting that if we do not have strict exogeneity, neither the OLS nor the GLS estimator would necessarily be unbiased. This is the case for some autoregressive processes, where strict exogeneity does not hold. However, if the regressors are “predetermined” (which is weaker than strict exogeneity), the OLS estimator will have some good large sample properties (such as “consistency” and “asymptotic normality”), even though it has serial correlation. Hayashi goes on to say:

> The GLS estimator, in contrast, does not have that redeeming feature. That is, if the error is not strictly exogenous but is merely predetermined, the GLS procedure to correct for serial correlation can make the estimator inconsistent (see Section 6.7). A procedure for explicitly taking serial correlation into account while maintaining consistency will be presented in
> Chapter 6.

I only studied the first two chapters of Hayashi's book and there is still a long way to go before I reach chapter 6, but I would like to understand the last quote better. Could you explain it to me or give me the intuition?  Could you give me an example where I can see how GLS fails to correct serial correlation in a context without strict exogeneity, but only with predetermined regressors?